# Inequality regarding matrix norm and positive definite matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, positive-definite

Is the following inequality true $$\frac{x^TB^TABx}{x^TAx}\le \Vert B \Vert^2$$ where *A* is a positive definite matrix, *B* is an arbitrary matrix, *x* is a column vector, and $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ is the matrix 2-norm. It seems true to me, and I've verified a lot of cases numerically, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Try $$A=\begin{bmatrix}10&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ x=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. In my original problem, _B_ = _I_ - _aUA_, where _U_ = diag(1/(1+sum(A(1,:))), 1/(1+sum(A(2,:))),..., 1/(1+sum(A(n,:)))), _a_ is a small positive number, _A_ is positive and positive definite, do you think the above inequality will be true?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this is not necessarily true.  For instance, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&4}, \quad B = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad x = \pmatrix{1\\0}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. In my original problem, _B_ = _I_ - _aUA_, where _U_ = diag(1/(1+sum(A(1,:))), 1/(1+sum(A(2,:))),..., 1/(1+sum(A(n,:)))), _a_ is a small positive number, _A_ is positive and positive definite, do you think the above inequality will be true?

Comment: I have no idea.  I recommend that you make a new post that asks this question given your specific definition of $B$.